# Gradient Layer at the bottom of UITextview

Tags: ios, ios5, ios7, uitextview

How can I have  the same effect in iOS `UITextView` like below image.
Blur effect from the bottom of `UITextView`

[image: Gradient at the bottom of UItextView]

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following: I tried the following with image but not UITextView

```
UIView *vwTest = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_textView.frame];
[vwTest setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[vwTest setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[self.view addSubview:vwTest];

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1] CGColor],
                   (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0] CGColor],
                   nil];

CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
[layer setFrame:vwTest.bounds];
[layer setColors:colors];
[layer setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];
[layer setEndPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.6f)];
[vwTest.layer setMask:layer];
```

Comment: `CAGradientLayer` will do it for sure but not on `textView.layer`. If you scroll, the gradient scrolls with it. I would suggest a minor modification. Place a `UIView` over the `textView` and mask the `UIView`. Also... swap the start and end color of gradient. _Actually, don't mind if I update your answer._

Comment: No Problem. Some how, our answer would help others. Thanks for your correction :)

Answer (score 0):

Just place an UIImageView which contains a gradient image from clear to white on top of the bottom of the text view. That's the easiest way I guess.

Comment: I want without UIImageview ,something by using CALayer[not sure]

Answer (score 0):

```
let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(textView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(textView.frame))
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.init(white: 1, alpha: 0).CGColor, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.6)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1)
            self.textview.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Charlie above did not work as is for me on Swift 5.x, I had to make some changes.

First add an UIView with an UITextView on it. Then I did apply the calare like this:

```
let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: textView.frame.width, height: textView.frame.height)
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.init(white: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.6)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
self.contentTextView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```